# Google Maps InfoWindow in ReactJS - is it possible to control the HTML outside of my content HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, google-maps

I have an `InfoWindow` in Google Maps that opens some of my HTML content in React.

```
    return (
        <div className="map-tooltip-wrapper">
            <div className="map-tooltip-image"><img src={image || ''} /></div>
            <div className="map-tooltip-title"><h5 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: unescape(title || '')}}></h5></div>
            <div className="map-tooltip-message"><p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: unescape(message || '')}}></p></div>
        </div>
    )
```

I can style the wrapper and everything within, however it's impossible to grab some divs that are outside to get rid (or hide) the area highlighted on a screen.

**How can I remove or hide the area highlighted on the screen?**

[image]

My styling is basic and trivial. I don't mind the vertical scrollbar. I would like to get rid of everything that is outside. As an exception the close `X` button could stay and be moved to the left and placed on top of the image.

I tried grabbing the `map-tooltip-wrapper` via jQuery and then go traverse each parent div but this is a nasty way a there is no guarantee that the structure will remain the same in the future since everything above is rendered by Google Maps and has some inline styles added dynamically.

[image]

I create `InfoWindow` by:

```
this.mapInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: content
});
```

Google documentation also [doesn't give much help](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows).

Answer (score 0):

[Customization](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#customize)

> The InfoWindow class does not offer customization. Instead, see the
>   [customized popup example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup) to see how to create a fully customized
>   popup.